# Tails of sums of Weibull random variables

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, real-analysis, measure-concentration

Suppose that $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ are i.i.d random variables distributed according to [Weibull distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) with shape $0 < \epsilon < 1$ (it means that $\mathbf{Pr}[X_i \geq t] = e^{-\Theta(t^{\epsilon})}$).

Now consider the random variable $S_n = X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n$, when $n$ tends to infinity.
Clearly, $\mathbf{E}[S_n] = O_{\epsilon}(n)$. Is it true that for some $C = C(\epsilon)$ we have $\mathbf{Pr}[S_n \geq C n] \leq e^{-\Omega_{\epsilon}(n^{\alpha})}$ for some $\alpha = \alpha(\epsilon) > 0$? If so, what is the largest $\alpha$ one can get?

The standard MGF-based methods that work nicely in similar situations are not applicable here due to the fact that $X_i$'s are heavy-tailed. My feeling is that this question must be studied somewhere.

Comment: I guess, the following reference may be useful for you, it's also pretty recent: [An Introduction to Heavy-Tailed and Subexponential Distributions, 2011](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/probability/book/978-1-4419-9472-1). Perhaps, available in Russian as well. Furthermore, [this paper](http://www.math.nsc.ru/LBRT/v1/dima/publications/rate_of_convergence.pdf) provides untight rates of convergence which hold however even in case you only have first two moments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The affirmative answer can be found in [this](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=tvp&paperid=1116&option_lang=eng) paper by A.V.Nagaev: essentially "the conjecture" is true for $\alpha = \varepsilon$ (which is clearly the best possible).

Answer (score 0):

1. $f(x) = cosh(x^{\alpha})$ is convex for $\alpha > \frac 12$ 
   so 2. $\mathbb E f(\frac {S_n} n) \le \mathbb E f(X) $ which, with chebyshev,  implies your claim for any $\frac 12 \le \alpha \le \epsilon$.  3.  For general case, replace $cosh$ with $\sum \frac {x^{nk}}{(nk)!}$ where K satisfies $\alpha k > 1$.  You have to know that this thing is about $e^x$, which can be gotten from the fact that it is $\sum_j e^{xe^{(2 \pi i j)/k}}/k$