# Concentration of sum of independent random variables

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, measure-concentration

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be i.i.d. sub-Gaussian random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$. That is, we have $\Pr[|X_i| > t] \leq \exp(1-t^2/K^2)$ for all $t>0$ and a parameter $K$.

Then we can use Bernsein-type inequalities to prove deviation bounds for the summation $S := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$ (after appropriate shifting). Namely, we can prove, for an absolute constant $c > 0$,

$$\Pr[S > n+t] \leq 2 \exp\left(-c\min\left(t^2/(K^4 n), t/K^2\right)\right).$$

Now suppose that, instead, we wish to derive deviation bounds for the summation $S_2 := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^4$. Obviously,

$\Pr[S_2 > t] \leq \Pr[S > \sqrt{t}]$ since $S_2 \leq S^2$, and one can use the above Bernstein-type bound for $S$. But is it possible to do better? Are there tighter concentration bounds for summation of powers of independent sub-exponential random variables?

Comment: Could you please take the time to revisit your post carefully and make some edits? Several statements are incorrect. I am unsure at this point if this is due to (a) some inadvertently unstated assumptions (e.g., that the $X_i \geq 0$), (b) multiple typos or (c) something more conceptual being missed here. I don't want to make any assumptions, so I'll leave it to you to make the needed edits. Cheers.

Comment: I added the assumption that the $X_i$ are centered variables (zero expectation). I don't catch any other missing points. You may assume that $X_i \geq 0$ but I don't think that's necessary. Is there anything specific that doesn't make sense?

Comment: By the way, the setting is exactly the same as Proposition 5.16 on Page 14 of the following: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.3027v7.pdf


Comment: Yes, I am familiar with R. Vershynin's work; the way you gave the first bound was a dead giveaway that this was the paper you were looking at. :-) Consider the case $X_i \in \{-1,+1\}$ with probability $1/2$ each. Certainly this satisfies your conditions, but $n = S_2 \leq S^2$ is false, in general. (Take $n=2$, for instance.) As a second example, take $X_i$ to be standard normal and consider $n = 1$ to see that $\mathbb P(S_2 > t) \leq \mathbb P(S > \sqrt{t})$ is false even when $S_2 \leq S^2$.

Comment: Sorry I had missed the absolute values in $S$ (question updated now). But that does not affect the case where the $X_i$ are non-negative. Hopefully that answers your first concern. For the second, note that normal random variables are not sub-exponential. Their second power is.

Comment: Dear Mahdi, I appreciate the edits and I am trying to be helpful, so let me encourage you to reread my first comment and take it to heart. It now appears that all three of the issues mentioned in that comment are in play here. Regarding your most recent edit and comment: (a) Your edit is incorrect and does not match Prop. 5.16 or the associated Cor. 5.17, (b) my standard normal example is entirely relevant and intended, as you will see if you examine it more carefully and (c) though somewhat immaterial thusfar, a normal random variable is most certainly subexponential (as is its square)!

Comment:  I edited the question again and rewritten sub-exponential variables as squared sub-Gaussian random variables, which is what I'm working with. I hope this resolves your issues about positivity, and makes the question more clear.

Comment: Hi Mahdi,

I thought i had a solution to your problem, but i made a silly mistake that invalidated it (hence the deleted post). However, you can easily get a lower bound for P[S_2 > t] by just making one the X_i's at least $t^{1/4}$. For sufficiently large $t$, my guess is that this will be tight up to constants - the event $\{S_2>t\}$ implies $\displaystyle \bigcup_{M} \{S > t /M \cap max X_i^2 = M\}$. You still need to overcome correlation issues, but this event should be dominated by just requiring one of the coordinates to be large.


Comment: Related (unanswered) question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/127364/chernoff-bound-in-the-not-quite-sub-exponential-case